# Segfault and/or "Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required..." when running scripts located in CIFS mounts

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I compiled PHP 5.4.22 and 5.5.6. In both versions I can't run any scripts that are located in a CIFS (SMB/Samba) mount.

If I try to run it the usual way, I get a weird error message:

```
user@machine:/mnt/windows# /opt/php/bin/php test.php
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'test.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

If I try to use the built-in server, I simply get a segmentation fault:

```
user@machine:/mnt/windows# /opt/php/bin/php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
PHP 5.5.6 Development Server started at Thu Dec  5 23:04:53 2013
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000
Document root is /smb
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
--------> here I load the website from a browser <--------
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the inode number in the mounted folder was huge and that made PHP freak out:

```
user@machine:/mnt/windows# ls -i test.php
69524319247729677 -rwxrwxrwx 1 65535 65535 26 Dec  4 23:28 test.php
```

It looks like [it's a feature of CIFS](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs):

> The UniqueID value is unique over the scope of the entire server and is often greater than 2 power 32. This value often makes programs that are not compiled with LFS (Large File Support), to trigger a glibc EOVERFLOW error as this won't fit in the target structure field. It is strongly recommended to compile your programs with LFS support (i.e. with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64) to prevent this problem. **You can also use "noserverino" mount option to generate inode numbers smaller than 2 power 32 on the client**. But you may not be able to detect hardlinks properly.

So I added `noserverino` to my mount options in `/etc/fstab`. After doing that and remounting the inode number is something nicer and everything works flawlessly:

```
user@machine:/mnt/windows# ls -i test.php
89 -rwxrwxrwx 1 65535 65535 26 Dec  4 23:28 test.php
user@machine:/mnt/windows# /opt/php/bin/php test.php
hello world
```

There seems to be [a PHP related bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45942) but it seems to have some side effects on performance [and other functions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53829).

---

**Update**: after doing this everything seems to be working, except that **the server can't send files bigger than a few dozen KB**. So we're at square one again.